# Pass in two variables to **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have an entry form for a GUI window that asks for a new setting and a value for that setting, which it then passes to another object that manages settings and expects **kwargs as input:

```
class SettingsForm(someFormClass):
    def onSubmit(self):
        new_setting = self.content['new setting'].get()
        new_value = self.content['value'].get()
        settings_instance.add_setting(new_setting=new_value)
```

This sets new_value to the literal string 'new_setting'. I've tried various ways to get around this, such as using a dictionary:

```
class SettingsForm(someFormClass):
    def onSubmit(self):
        new_setting = self.content['new setting'].get()
        new_value = self.content['value'].get()
        mydict = {}
        mydict[new_setting] = new_value
        settings_instance.add_setting(**mydict)
```

This works, but doesn't make much sense for a single pair of values... is there an obvious way that I'm missing?

Comment: using `….add_setting(**{mydict: new_value})` might make it more readable but that's all I can think of

Comment: thanks, that actually works quite nicely.